# SwiftUI published variable not updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to set a published variable named allCountries. In my DispatchQueue, it's being set and is actually printing out the correct information to the console. In my content view, nothing is in the array. In the init function on the content view, I'm calling the the function that will fetch the data and set the variable but when I print to the console, the variable is blank. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is where I'm fetching the data

```
class GetCountries: ObservableObject {

@Published var allCountries = [Countries]()

func getAllPosts() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "apiURL")
        else {
            fatalError("URL does not work!")
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
        do {
            if let data = data {
                let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Countries].self, from: data)


                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.allCountries = posts
                    print(self.allCountries)

                }
            } else  {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("didn't work")
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

}

Here's my content view

```
struct ContentView: View {

var countries = ["Select Your Country", "Canada", "Mexico", "United States"]

@ObservedObject var countries2 = GetCountries()

@State private var selectedCountries = 0

init() {
    GetCountries().getAllPosts()
    print(countries2.allCountries)

}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

        ZStack {

            VStack {
                Text("\(countries2.allCountries.count)")}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening in the `init` of your `ContentView`. You're calling the TYPE's function `getAllPosts`, but then you're trying to access the data of a new INSTANCE of that Type `countries2`. Your `countries2.allCountries` instance property really has no relationship to the `GetCountries.allCountries` type property.

Does that even compile? Usually you need to define a class's functions and properties as `static` if you want to call them on the Type itself and not on an instance of it.

Maybe it's weirdness because you're trying to do this in the `ContentView`'s init, rather than after it has initialized.

There's probably two things you need to do to fix this.

Step one would be to let your custom initializer actually initialize `countries2`.

And step two would be to call `countries2.getAllPosts` within that custom initializer, which will populate the instance property you're trying to access in  `countries2.allCountries`.

Try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var countries = ["Select Your Country", "Canada", "Mexico", "United States"]

// You'll initialize this in the custom init
@ObservedObject var countries2: GetCountries

@State private var selectedCountries = 0

init() {
    countries2 = GetCountries()
    countries2.getAllPosts()
    print(countries2.allCountries)

}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

        ZStack {

            VStack {
                Text("\(countries2.allCountries.count)")}}}
```

But I'm not sure if you're going to run into problems with the async call within the `ContentView` initializer. It might be better practice to move that into a function which is called when the view is loaded, rather than when the SwiftUI struct is initialized.

To do that you move your networking calls into a function of `ContentView` (instead of its `init`), then use an `.onAppear` modifier to your view, which will call a function when the `NavigationView` appears. (Now that we're not using a custom initializer, we'll need to go back to initializing the `countries2` property.)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var countries = ["Select Your Country", "Canada", "Mexico", "United States"]

    // We're initializing countries2 again
    @ObservedObject var countries2 = GetCountries()

    @State private var selectedCountries = 0

    // This is the function that will get your country data
    func getTheCountries() {
        countries2.getAllPosts()
        print(countries2.allCountries)

    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("\(countries2.allCountries.count)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: getTheCountries) // Execute this when the NavigationView appears
    }
}
```

Note with this approach. Depending on your UI architecture, every time NavigationView appears, it will call `getTheCountries`. If you make `NavigationLink` calls to new views, then it may get reloaded loaded if you go back to this first page. But you can easily add a check within `getTheCountries` to see if the work is actually required.

Comment: thanks for the answer but neither one of these ways worked for me.

Comment: He didn't call `getAllPosts()` on the the type. He called it on a fresh instance. Note the parentheses after the type name. Nonetheless, the rest of what you said is right.

Answer (score 1):

It should be used one same instance to initiate request & read results, so here is fixed variant:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var countries = ["Select Your Country", "Canada", "Mexico", "United States"]

    @ObservedObject var countries2 = GetCountries()   // member
    @State private var selectedCountries = 0

    init() {
        // GetCountries().getAllPosts()      // [x] local variable
        // print(countries2.allCountries)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("\(countries2.allCountries.count)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear { self.countries2.getAllPosts() } // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets the array count correct but when I change the text view to Text("\(countries2.allCountries[0].Culture)")

it says index out of range for some reason.

Comment: @C.Jones, fetching countries is asynchronous operation, so at very start array is empty and view shows correctly count as 0, and then when results appear it is updated correspondingly, but if you hardcode access to 0 element then at start you get exception, because in empty array there is no [0] element. It needs to use ForEach to iterate the countries and show results, it works correctly with empty array, so will not be any exception at start.

Answer (score 1):

Change ObservedObject to StateObject

```
@StateObject var countries2 = GetCountries()
```

Comment: This suggestion saved me. Thanks a lot.